# Not Launching iOS Simulator in openCV Example in ios

Tags: ios, xcode

I have Integrated the openCV framework in my iOS app . It have compiled successfully . But When I click on run it shows the Status and Running and after few seconds it shows the Finished Running . But the app not launching the iOS Simulator. Please  help me to solve this Issue . I have downloaded some Examples of OpenCV . Those are also behaving like the above .

Comment: Check do you have the simulator installed which you define in your setting. If not then install, you'll get that option from 'more simulator' in XCode. Let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply mohit, I have all versions of Simulators i.e iOS Simulator 4.3,5.1,6.0 ...

Comment: Then, check what your target set, It seems your target is the openCV Framework.

Comment: Hi Mohit, +1 for you . Your Idea has given a hint to my mind . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting contents of `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` and re-run